# How to find E[|Product of Two Gaussians|]

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation, conditional-expectation

---

**The Problem**

Let $Y \sim N(0,B)$ and $Z \sim N(0,A)$. I would like to find 
$$\boxed{\mathbb{E}\left[|YZ|\right]}$$ This seems like a natural question that would arise in probability theory, but I have not been able to find any results online or in textbooks. (Note: Here $Y$,$Z$ are NOT necessarily independent. However, they are jointly normal with known pdf $f_{Y,Z}(y,z)$; nevertheless simply evaluating the double integral to directly find $\mathbb{E}[|YZ|]$ directly seems to not work.)

---

**The Attempt**

By the law of total expectation, we have that $\mathbb{E} \left[|YZ| \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[\mathbb{E}[(\mid YZ \mid )|Z] \right]$. So, first we will try to find $\mathbb{E}[(\mid YZ \mid )|Z]$. Well,
$$\mathbb{E}[(\mid YZ \mid )|Z]=|Z| \mathbb{E}[(\mid Y\mid) |Z]$$

We note that $|Y|$ follows a half-normal distribution. This is where I am stuck. I'm not sure where to go from here, perhaps I need to use some results pertaining to the folded normal dist. Or maybe try a different approach entirely to find $\mathbb{E}[|YZ|]$.

*Edit*: We have that $Y|Z \sim N \left(0+\frac{\sqrt{B}}{\sqrt{A}}\rho(z-0),(1-\rho^2 )B \right)$ where $\rho$ is the correlation coefficient. Then $|Y|Z|$ follows a folded normal distribution, so we can get $\mathbb{E}[|Y|Z|]$ from that. The issue here is that we want $\mathbb{E}[(|Y|)|Z]$.

---

Any help with this problem is immensely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are they at least jointly normal?

Comment: I don't think finding $E[XY]$ is easy without having the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ or the covariance, but who knows...

Comment: @E-A Yes, $Y$ and $Z$ are jointly normal, so i definitely have the joint distribution $f_{Y,Z}(y,z)$.

Comment: If $(X, Y) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$ with $\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix}$, then

$$ \mathbb{E}[|XY|] = \frac{2}{\pi}\left( \sqrt{\det\Sigma} + b \arctan\left( \frac{b}{\sqrt{\det\Sigma}} \right) \right). $$

Comment: @SangchulLee !!! Nice! Where did you get this from/ how to derive it ?   I(f you write this as an answer with some justification I'll accept it .     Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found in Corollary 3.1 in this - [Guassian Integrals Involving Absolute Value Functions](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.imsc/1265119260)